# CrystalReports Embedded reports in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We currently have a set of crystal reports used for winforms projects embedded into a dll. This has been working well for us as the dll exposes a simple constructor for each report to pass needed parameters.

A property can then be retrieved which is the:

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass object which you send to the report viewer to see the report.

I thought it would be easy to add this dll to an ASP.NET project and do the same. However it seems ASP.NET reports require a path to pick up the actual .rpt file.

From what I can find on the internet it says embedded reports are not supported in CR 2005 and CR 2008 basic but says nothing about **CR 2008 Full Version** (Which is what we have). Is there a way to do it with this version?

If not any work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have managed to discover this is not possbile. I modified my report classes to have a constructor for web and a constructor for windows so the windows one can pick up the embedded reports and the web the standalone ones from bin. This is not ideal but there seems no other solution.